# XAMPP causing 'The connection was reset' error in Firefox

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm experiencing problems when running a specific PHP file; in the latest Firefox it keeps giving the error 'The connection was reset' (I've tried running the PHP file in a different browser - the latest Internet Explorer but get the same problem).

I've also tried completely uninstalling both XAMPP and Firefox (default browser) - then reinstalling them.

I have even tried clearing the cache in Firefox and also ran CCleaner.

I'm not sure what is causing this problem as when I run the exact PHP file on another machine (on Windows 7 - with XAMPP & latest Firefox) it works perfectly fine and it is not like the PHP file is fairly complex/resource intensive (it does not even call/use MySQL!)? :S

I have tried integrating some debug/error reporting code within the PHP file - but that does not produce/do anything, but I've noticed whenever the PHP file is ran; apache does create/update an 'error.log' file within the 'XAMPP/apache/logs' folder with the following errors:

```
[Tue May 28 07:31:18.158004 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 2404:tid 328] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue May 28 07:31:18.283009 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2404:tid 328] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 28 07:31:18.283009 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2404:tid 328] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Tue May 28 07:31:18.283009 2013] [core:notice] [pid 2404:tid 328] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\users\\admin\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Users/Admin/XAMPP/apache'
[Tue May 28 07:31:18.283009 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2404:tid 328] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4112
```

PS-1: I noticed it is referring to SSL within the above log - I'm not using SSL?.

PS-2: The XAMPP settings are exactly the same since the install (like I have not modified/updated php.ini or have added anything that does within the .htaccess file).

**OS:** Windows 8 (64 bit)

**XAMPP:** 1.8.1 (installed relatively to user 'Admin' => 'C:/Users/Admin/XAMPP')

**Browsers:** Latest - Firefox (default) and Internet Explorer, both have NO third-party extensions/add-ons installed/enabled

**Security programs:** Avira Free Antivirus, Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (PRO) and KeyScrambler (Personal)

Answer (score 0):

I had what might be a similar problem a few years back, and, if I recall correctly, it was caused by using Notepad to write the script. Upon switching to another text editor the problem was fixed. As I recall, there were hidden characters inserted by Notepad (or whatever it was that I had used).